# Android Studio Closed All time in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Hi Every Time My Studio will be closed and my files are not saved

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Please see the log bellow. I have tried what they said in log but no use. Help me

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1bd6e4fb46, pid=9336, tid=139757507479296
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x643b46]  InstanceKlass::oop_oop_iterate_nv(oopDesc*, ParScanWithoutBarrierClosure*)+0x266
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f1bd0021800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00007f1bd4868000,0x00007f1bd4969000] [id=9341]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x0000000104dcdbe0


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RBX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

Stack: [0x00007f1bd4868000,0x00007f1bd4969000],  sp=0x00007f1bd4967a70,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x643b46]  InstanceKlass::oop_oop_iterate_nv(oopDesc*, ParScanWithoutBarrierClosure*)+0x266
V  [libjvm.so+0x92cc47]  ParScanThreadState::trim_queues(int)+0x167
V  [libjvm.so+0x92cf67]  ParEvacuateFollowersClosure::do_void()+0x37
V  [libjvm.so+0x92bf56]  ParNewGenTask::work(unsigned int)+0x1b6
V  [libjvm.so+0xacc17f]  GangWorker::loop()+0xcf
V  [libjvm.so+0x910de8]  java_start(Thread*)+0x108

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f1ba4061000 JavaThread "JobScheduler FJ pool 0/4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9483, stack(0x00007f1b191de000,0x00007f1b192df000)]
  0x00007f1b30482000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9482, stack(0x00007f1b41d66000,0x00007f1b41e67000)]
  0x00007f1ba4043800 JavaThread "JobScheduler FJ pool 2/4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9480, stack(0x00007f1b1b2e7000,0x00007f1b1b3e8000)]
  0x00007f1ba0206000 JavaThread "JobScheduler FJ pool 1/4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9478, stack(0x00007f1b1b1e6000,0x00007f1b1b2e7000)]
  0x00007f1b3c16a800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9475, stack(0x00007f1b1a6df000,0x00007f1b1a7e0000)]
  0x00007f1b33149800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 11" [_thread_blocked, id=9474, stack(0x00007f1b435dd000,0x00007f1b436de000)]
  0x00007f1b9405b000 JavaThread "JobScheduler FJ pool 3/4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9473, stack(0x00007f1b1b0e5000,0x00007f1b1b1e6000)]
  0x00007f1b88007000 JavaThread "Change List Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9468, stack(0x00007f1b200bd000,0x00007f1b201be000)]
  0x0000000001785800 JavaThread "Device Client Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=9464, stack(0x00007f1b1a7e0000,0x00007f1b1a8e1000)]
  0x00007f1b64074800 JavaThread "Device List Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=9463, stack(0x00007f1b1a8e1000,0x00007f1b1a9e2000)]
  0x00007f1b642a3000 JavaThread "Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=9456, stack(0x00007f1b1a9e2000,0x00007f1b1aae3000)]
  0x00007f1b3c169000 JavaThread "Alarm pool(own)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9455, stack(0x00007f1b1aee3000,0x00007f1b1afe4000)]
  0x00007f1b32f45800 JavaThread "Icons" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9454, stack(0x00007f1b1afe4000,0x00007f1b1b0e5000)]
  0x00007f1b301a9800 JavaThread "RefCountingStorage write content helper" [_thread_blocked, id=9431, stack(0x00007f1b41f6e000,0x00007f1b4206f000)]
  0x00007f1b32cbb800 JavaThread "FS Synchronizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9415, stack(0x00007f1b1bbfe000,0x00007f1b1bcff000)]
  0x00007f1b32cb4000 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 10" [_thread_blocked, id=9414, stack(0x00007f1b1bcff000,0x00007f1b1be00000)]
  0x00007f1b3c167800 JavaThread "Alarm pool(own)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9409, stack(0x00007f1b201be000,0x00007f1b202bf000)]
  0x00007f1b32e25800 JavaThread "EditorNotifications executor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9406, stack(0x00007f1b206bf000,0x00007f1b207c0000)]
  0x00007f1b3c148000 JavaThread "Alarm pool(own)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9405, stack(0x00007f1b22af4000,0x00007f1b22bf5000)]
  0x00007f1b3c147000 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9402, stack(0x00007f1b211c0000,0x00007f1b212c1000)]
  0x00007f1b240ab000 JavaThread "Encoding detection thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9401, stack(0x00007f1b21ec1000,0x00007f1b21fc2000)]
  0x00007f1b5404d000 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 8" [_thread_blocked, id=9398, stack(0x00007f1b21fc2000,0x00007f1b220c3000)]
  0x00007f1b32add800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 7" [_thread_blocked, id=9397, stack(0x00007f1b224f0000,0x00007f1b225f1000)]
  0x00007f1b32ac5000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9393, stack(0x00007f1b225f1000,0x00007f1b226f2000)]
  0x00007f1b32aa8800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6" [_thread_blocked, id=9392, stack(0x00007f1b226f2000,0x00007f1b227f3000)]
  0x00007f1b32a2f800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9391, stack(0x00007f1b229f3000,0x00007f1b22af4000)]
  0x00007f1b3295e800 JavaThread "Animations" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9388, stack(0x00007f1b231fe000,0x00007f1b232ff000)]
  0x00007f1b3c0d1800 JavaThread "Alarm pool(shared)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9387, stack(0x00007f1b232ff000,0x00007f1b23400000)]
  0x00007f1b31338800 JavaThread "Document commit thread" [_thread_blocked, id=9386, stack(0x00007f1b400bb000,0x00007f1b401bc000)]
  0x00007f1b3c174000 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9384, stack(0x00007f1b401bc000,0x00007f1b402bd000)]
  0x00007f1b3099e000 JavaThread "FocusManager timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9382, stack(0x00007f1b402bd000,0x00007f1b403be000)]
  0x00007f1b3099c800 JavaThread "Shared SimpleTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9381, stack(0x00007f1b403be000,0x00007f1b404bf000)]
  0x00007f1b30947000 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9380, stack(0x00007f1b6802d000,0x00007f1b68066000)]
  0x00007f1b308b0800 JavaThread "Performance watcher" [_thread_blocked, id=9378, stack(0x00007f1b40906000,0x00007f1b40a07000)]
  0x00007f1b308ac000 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 4" [_thread_blocked, id=9377, stack(0x00007f1b40a07000,0x00007f1b40b08000)]
  0x00007f1b30691800 JavaThread "StoreRefreshStatusThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9375, stack(0x00007f1b5ace3000,0x00007f1b5ade4000)]
  0x00007f1b3068f800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 3" [_thread_blocked, id=9374, stack(0x00007f1b40d08000,0x00007f1b40e09000)]
  0x00007f1b3068e000 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 2" [_thread_blocked, id=9373, stack(0x00007f1b40e09000,0x00007f1b40f0a000)]
  0x00007f1b30688800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1" [_thread_blocked, id=9372, stack(0x00007f1b40f0a000,0x00007f1b4100b000)]
  0x00007f1b30685000 JavaThread "Flushing thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9370, stack(0x00007f1b4100b000,0x00007f1b4110c000)]
  0x00007f1b3009a000 JavaThread "ZipFileCache Dispose" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9369, stack(0x00007f1b42e76000,0x00007f1b42f77000)]
  0x00007f1b30022800 JavaThread "Periodic tasks thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9368, stack(0x00007f1b43eff000,0x00007f1b44000000)]
  0x00007f1b3c143000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0 1.2#AI-141.1980579, eap:false" [_thread_blocked, id=9367, stack(0x00007f1b433db000,0x00007f1b434dc000)]
  0x00007f1b3c15e000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=9366, stack(0x00007f1b434dc000,0x00007f1b435dd000)]
  0x00007f1b3c04f800 JavaThread "Lock thread" [_thread_in_native, id=9364, stack(0x00007f1b43bfe000,0x00007f1b43cff000)]
  0x00007f1b3c048000 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9363, stack(0x00007f1b5808b000,0x00007f1b580c4000)]
  0x00007f1bd000b000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=9337, stack(0x00007f1bd82cb000,0x00007f1bd83cc000)]
  0x00007f1bd02ef000 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9354, stack(0x00007f1b6b7ee000,0x00007f1b6b8ef000)]
  0x00007f1bd02d6800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9353, stack(0x00007f1b6beff000,0x00007f1b6c000000)]
  0x00007f1bd0102800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9351, stack(0x00007f1b9a1a6000,0x00007f1b9a2a7000)]
  0x00007f1bd00fd800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9350, stack(0x00007f1b9a2a7000,0x00007f1b9a3a8000)]
  0x00007f1bd00fb800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9349, stack(0x00007f1b9a3a8000,0x00007f1b9a4a9000)]
  0x00007f1bd00f9000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9348, stack(0x00007f1b9a4a9000,0x00007f1b9a5aa000)]
  0x00007f1bd00f7000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9347, stack(0x00007f1b9a5aa000,0x00007f1b9a6ab000)]
  0x00007f1bd00f6000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9346, stack(0x00007f1b9a6ab000,0x00007f1b9a7ac000)]
  0x00007f1bd00be000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9345, stack(0x00007f1b9ae8e000,0x00007f1b9af8f000)]
  0x00007f1bd00bc000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9344, stack(0x00007f1b9af8f000,0x00007f1b9b090000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f1bd00b7000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f1b9b090000,0x00007f1b9b191000] [id=9343]
  0x00007f1bd0105800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f1b9a0a5000,0x00007f1b9a1a6000] [id=9352]

=>0x00007f1bd0021800 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00007f1bd4868000,0x00007f1bd4969000] [id=9341]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007f1bd0007160] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f1bd00b7000
[0x00007f1bd00076e0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f1b3c169000


Event: 106.588 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=12 (full 3):
 par new generation   total 306688K, used 303500K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000094cc0000, 0x0000000094cc0000)
  eden space 272640K,  98% used [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000090723178, 0x0000000090a40000)
  from space 34048K, 100% used [0x0000000090a40000, 0x0000000092b80000, 0x0000000092b80000)
  to   space 34048K,   0% used [0x0000000092b80000, 0x0000000092b80000, 0x0000000094cc0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 707840K, used 258729K [0x0000000094cc0000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 146432K, capacity 148700K, committed 149508K, reserved 1177600K
  class space    used 21037K, capacity 21745K, committed 21756K, reserved 1048576K
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xbootclasspath/a:android-studio/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/vj/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio 
java_command: com.intellij.idea.Main
java_class_path (initial): android-studio/bin/../lib/bootstrap.jar:android-studio/bin/../lib/extensions.jar:android-studio/bin/../lib/util.jar:android-studio/bin/../lib/jdom.jar:android-studio/bin/../lib/log4j.jar:android-studio/bin/../lib/trove4j.jar:android-studio/bin/../lib/jna.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=android-studio/bin:
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"

uname:Linux 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 60985, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:3.15 1.92 1.51

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        7827712 kB
MemFree:         1094836 kB
Buffers:           18772 kB
Cached:           778296 kB
SwapCached:        37488 kB
Active:          4039692 kB
Inactive:        1463136 kB
Active(anon):    3712116 kB
Inactive(anon):  1066056 kB
Active(file):     327576 kB
Inactive(file):   397080 kB
Unevictable:         272 kB
Mlocked:             272 kB
SwapTotal:       8166396 kB
SwapFree:        8103256 kB
Dirty:               492 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4678792 kB
Mapped:           932912 kB
Shmem:             72412 kB
Slab:             151124 kB
SReclaimable:      94960 kB
SUnreclaim:        56164 kB
KernelStack:        6144 kB
PageTables:        58820 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    12080252 kB
Committed_AS:   11133304 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      392868 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359340068 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   2000896 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     2749492 kB
DirectMap2M:     5285888 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB


CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x9
cpu MHz     : 3400.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 6784.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x9
cpu MHz     : 3400.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 6784.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x9
cpu MHz     : 3400.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 6784.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x9
cpu MHz     : 3400.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 6784.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 7827712k(1094836k free), swap 8166396k(8103256k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_45-b14), built on Apr 10 2015 10:07:45 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Tue Jul 21 20:49:06 2015
elapsed time: 106 seconds (0d 0h 1m 46s)
```

Comment: review  the JVM you are running AS on and why..... im on ubuntu 12.04 & STUDIO_JDK=/home/rob/jre/jdk1.7.0_72   . this jdk ONLY for AS. nothing else.